# Function doesn't return the result of API call

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a translation app that uses google translation API.
Code

```js
const apiTranslate = (() => {
    const _API_KEY = "api-key";
    async function getTranslation(text) {
        let res = await axios.post(
            `https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=${_API_KEY}`,
            { q: text, target: "de" }
        );
        let translation = res.data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
        console.log(translation);
        return translation;
    }
    return Object.assign({}, {getTranslation});
})();

let text = "hello world";
const {getTranslation} = apiTranslate;
const message = getTranslation(text);
console.log(message);
```

It returns: A promise object with prototype, promiseState and promiseResult properties.
It should return: Hello walt.
The value of translation is correct as I log it in the code.

Comment: You've got an asynchronous operation and you're expecting it to behave as if it were synchronous.

Comment: `getTranslation` is asynchronous. Try: `(async () => {
  let text = "hello world";
  const { getTranslation } = apiTranslate;
  const message = await getTranslation(text);
  console.log(message);
})()`

Comment: Yah thanx I just read a related question below and I got my answer. I've to use await.

Comment: When you call ```getTranslation(text)```, it returns a *Promise*, not the actual translated text. This is why you see a *Promise* when you log message. To get the translated text, you need to wait for the *Promise* to resolve. This can be done using the ```then``` method of the *Promise*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. you are right. `getTranslation` will return a promise as its an `async` function.

So, you can use either an await or then to get the return from it.

One:
In your case, if you want to read the data in your script body,

```
let text = "hello world";
const {getTranslation} = apiTranslate;

getTranslation(text).then(message=>{
    console.log(message);
});
```

Two:
Or if you want to assign to a variable `message` for further processing, then, you need to write a function.

```
const doTranslate = async ()=> {
    let text = "hello world";
    const {getTranslation} = apiTranslate;
    const message = await getTranslation(text);
    console.log(message);
}
```

Three:
Another approach declares an immediate calling function.

```
(async () => {
    let text = "hello world";
    const { getTranslation } = apiTranslate;
    const message = await getTranslation(text);
    console.log(message);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
async function translateText() {
    let text = "hello world";
    const {getTranslation} = apiTranslate;
    try {
         getTranslation(text).then((res=>{
            console.log(res)
         }));
       
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during translation:", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).